# 64GB vs 128GB SSD cache drive

Tags: ssd, speed, storage, hybrid-storage, hard-drive-cache

I have a Lenovo Y510p which I've had for about a year. After adding some RAM the other day I saw that it has an open m2 NGFF slot into which I can put a SSD drive. 
So I'm planning on buying a SSD drive to use as a cache drive for the main HDD using Expresscache. I don't want to move the OS and program files over to the SSD; I simply don't want to take the risk of breaking something when I have so much stuff set up already.

Now I've been looking online, and it seems that SSD cache software doesn't use more than 64GB of your SSD. So I'm wondering, will buying a 128GB SSD show any significant improvement over simply using a 64GB SSD?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes higher capacity SSDs have faster speeds.

The remaining part of the SSD beyond 64GB will be accessible in the Disk Management to partition as a separate drive.